# Where is the Black Maiden?

Tags: demons-souls

Just started playing Demon's Souls again. I played through the Tutorial area and then went to the Nexus. I didn't bother going to speak to her and just ran straight through right up to the Phalanx boss.

I thought I'd utilise my souls at this point and go back to the Nexus to make the battle easier. However, I can't find the Black Maiden anywhere to trade my souls. I have searched every inch of the Nexus that I am currently allowed.

I always remembered her sitting down on the stairs on the arch stone to Boletaria, or laying down on the floor on the opposite side?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can't redeem souls until after you beat the Phalanx boss and talk to the monumental.

She has 4 or 5 locations that I remember her at. The easiest way to find her if she is not at one of those locations is to warp to world and then warp back to the nexus. (she is usually standing next to the world of the last world you warped from)

Comment: Ah that makes sense. I guess its just because in Dark Souls you can pretty much do it straight away I assumed it worked the same.